# How to do a union of multiple queryset from a clickhouse ORM

Tags: django, django-models, clickhouse

In a Django search app, I want to query a clickhouse database (using the infi.clickhouse_orm library) for pairs of values such as (a=1 AND b>=1.5) OR (a=2 AND b>=1). In SQL this could be done with

```
select * from table where a == 1 and b >= 1.5 UNION ALL select * from table where a == 2 and b >= 1
```

Looking at other exemples I have tried:

With the queryset defined as

```
qs = TABLE.objects_in(db)
qs_1 = qs.filter(A__eq=1, B__gte=1.5)
qs_2 = qs.filter(A__eq=2, B__gte=1)
```

The | operator

```
qs_union = qs_1 | qs_2
```

which returns

```
unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'
```

The UNION operator

```
qs_union = qs_1.union(qs_2)
```

which returns

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'union'
```

and the Q objects

```
qs_union = qs.filter(Q(A__eq=1, B__gte=1.5) | Q(A__eq=2, B__gte=1))
```

which returns

```
'Q' object has no attribute 'to_sql'
```

From a clickhouse models, how do you perfom a union of 2, or more, queryset?

Thanks!

Comment: The `Q`s you use are probably *not* imported from the clickhouse ORM, but Django's Q objects?

Comment: As for the `UNION ALL`, I can not immediately find something in the GitHub repository, so I'm not sure that is implemented in the ORM: https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.clickhouse_orm/search?q=union&unscoped_q=union

Comment: You're going to have to use `Model.objects.raw('select f1, f2 from table1 union all select f1, f2 from table2')`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are correct that I am importing the ```Q``` from Django. The clickhouse documentation mentions the ```Q```s here: [link](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.clickhouse_orm/blob/develop/docs/querysets.md#querysets) but importing it from clickhouse results in ```cannot import name 'Q' from 'infi.clickhouse_orm' ```. Thank you for you help!

Comment: If anyone ever stubble upon this issue, ```Q``` is hidden in ```infi.clickhouse_orm.query```. This allows the Q objects to work and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: you should use the `Q` class of `infi.clickhouse_orm.query`, like:

```
from infi.clickhouse_orm.query import Q
```

The [`Q`-class in `info.clickhouse_orm` [GitHub]](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.clickhouse_orm/blob/64d15cf3b685fa130e78be5b54920b3b781447db/src/infi/clickhouse_orm/query.py#L204) has a `to_sql` method:

> ```
> class Q(object):
>
>     # ...
>
>     def to_sql(self, model_cls):
>         if self._fovs:
>             sql = ' {} '.format(self._mode).join(fov.to_sql(model_cls) for fov in self._fovs)
>         else:
>             if self._l_child and self._r_child:
>                 sql = '({} {} {})'.format(
>                         self._l_child.to_sql(model_cls), self._mode, self._r_child.to_sql(model_cls))
>             else:
>                 return '1'
>         if self._negate:
>             sql = 'NOT (%s)' % sql
>         return sql
> ```

Since the errors says it can not find the `to_sql`, it looks like you did not use that `Q`-class, but Django's `Q` class.